# Add XML attribute in mssql using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

i want output

```
<CustomerName>
<Customer id='1'>
<Name>xyz</Name>
</Customer>
<Customer id='2'>
<Name>Abc</Name>
</Customer>
</CustomerName>
```

for this output i wrote SP

```
SELECT
          '' AS [CustomerName],      
          (SELECT 
          Name[Customer/Name]
 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS[CustomerName/Customer]
          FOR XML PATH('')
```

not able to add Id attribute, please help me

Comment: It looks like part of your SP is missing - can you show the whole thing? Also, what does your data look like?

Comment: @bukko SP is complete..my data look like <CustomerName>
<Customer>
<Name>xyz</Name>
</Customer>
<Customer>
<Name>Abc</Name>
</Customer>
</CustomerName>

Comment: SP's begin with `CREATE PROCEDURE`. Also, I meant your input data i.e. tables, not your output XML.

Comment: @bukko 
Create Procedure GetXML
ID BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
          '' AS [CustomerName],      
          (SELECT 
          Name[Customer/Name]
FROM Customer where CusId=ID
 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS[CustomerName/Customer]
          FOR XML PATH('')
END


This is full SP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tblCust TABLE(id INT, CustomerName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblCust VALUES
 (1,'xyz')
,(2,'Abc');

SELECT id AS [@id]
      ,CustomerName AS [Name]
FROM @tblCust  
FOR XML PATH('Customer'),ROOT('CustomerName')
```

This is the result

```
<CustomerName>
  <Customer id="1">
    <Name>xyz</Name>
  </Customer>
  <Customer id="2">
    <Name>Abc</Name>
  </Customer>
</CustomerName>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [@id] = t.id, [Name] = t.name
FROM (
    VALUES (1, 'name'), (2, 'name2')
) t (id, name)
FOR XML PATH('Customer'), ROOT('CustomerName')
```

Comment: Ha, gotcha! Next time you'll win again :-)